# React app fails on Heroku with JS heap allocation error

Tags: javascript, reactjs, heroku, d3-org-chart

I have a React app, using the `d3-org-chart` package, which runs fine locally.
However, when deployed to Heroku, on startup it produces a

> JavaScript heap out of memory - allocation error

The allocated heap size on Heroku is 1024MB, however, locally, even when I do restrict the heap size to the same limit

```
"start": "react-scripts --max_old_space_size=1024 start",
"build": "react-scripts --max_old_space_size=1024 build"
```

it runs. When testing locally, the app doesn't require more than ~50MB, not even close to the limit set up on Heroku.

Is there a reason for the different behavior locally and when deployed? I cannot change the memory size limit on Heroku, so that is not a solution for me.